# How to stop a return 'else' value on Arduino

Tags: if-statement, arduino, serial-port, communication

I use 'if-else' with serial communication in Arduino. I am sending data in 'if' and 'else' sections using serial communication. But I can not stop sending data in the serial communications section. How can I provide it?

For example,

```cpp
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.avaliable() > 0) {

        if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH)
        {
            Serial.print("Yes");
        }
        else {
            Serial.print("No");
        }
    }
}
```

When I give number 5 to the number pin 2 , "Yes" flows continuously through the serial port. I know it's in the 'loop' section. But how do I stop it? So when I give the relevant pin to 5 V, can I get one response?

Answer (score 0):

Save your state into a [volatile](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/volatile) [global variable](https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/scope) and print only if the state is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the *loop()* function is called an infinite number of times.

You have two options:

1. Move the code from *loop()* to *setup()* and let the *loop()* function be empty

   ```cpp
   void setup() {

       Serial.begin(9600);
       pinMode(2, INPUT);

       if (Serial.avaliable() > 0) {

           if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH)
           {
               Serial.print("Yes");
           }
           else {
               Serial.print("No");
           }
       }
   }

   void loop() {

   }
   ```
2. Add some control logic like this

   ```cpp
   boolean alreadySent = false;

   void setup() {
       Serial.begin(9600);
       pinMode(2, INPUT);
   }

   void loop() {

       if (Serial.avaliable() > 0) {

           if(alreadySent == false) {

               if (digitalRead(2) == HIGH)
               {
                   Serial.print("Yes");
               }
               else {
                   Serial.print("No");
               }

               alreadySent = true;
           }
       }
   }
   ```